# Beautiful Soup And While Statement

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find the first 30 TED Videos (Name of Video and URL) using the following BeautifulSoup script:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

total_pages = 3
page_count = 1
count = 1

url = 'http://www.ted.com/talks?page='

while page_count < total_pages:

    page = urllib2.urlopen("%s%d") %(url, page_count)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    link = soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and tag.findParent('dt', 'thumbnail'))

    outfile = open("test.html", "w")

    print >> outfile, """<head>
            <head>
                    <title>TED Talks Index</title>
            </head>

            <body>

            <br><br><center>

            <table cellpadding=15 cellspacing=0 style='border:1px solid #000;'>"""

    print >> outfile, "<tr><th style='border-bottom:2px solid #E16543; border-right:1px solid #000;'><b>###</b></th><th style='border-bottom:2px solid #E16543; border-right:1px solid #000;'>Name</th><th style='border-bottom:2px solid #E16543;'>URL</th></tr>"

    ted_link = 'http://www.ted.com/'

    for anchor in link:
            print >> outfile, "<tr style='border-bottom:1px solid #000;'><td style='border-right:1px solid #000;'>%s</td><td style='border-right:1px solid #000;'>%s</td><td>http://www.ted.com%s</td></tr>" % (count, anchor['title'], anchor['href'])

    count = count + 1

    print >> outfile, """</table>
                    </body>
                    </html>"""

    page_count = page_count + 1
```

The code looks alright minus two things:

1. count doesn't seem to be incremented. It only goes through and finds the first page's content, ie: the first ten, not thirty, videos. Why?
2. This bit of the code gives me a lot of errors. I don't know how else to implement what I want here logically (with the urlopen("%s%d"):

Code:

```
total_pages = 3
page_count = 1
count = 1

url = 'http://www.ted.com/talks?page='

while page_count < total_pages:

page = urllib2.urlopen("%s%d") %(url, page_count)
```

Comment: It won't fix your problem but you have two opening `<head>` tags instead of a `<html>` and `<head>` tag: (I.E `print >> outfile, """<head>` should be `print >> outfile, """<html>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, simplify the loop and eliminate a few variables, which amount to boilerplate cruft in this case:

```
for pagenum in xrange(1, 4):  # The 4 is annoying, write it as 3+1 if you like.
  url = "http://www.ted.com/talks?page=%d" % pagenum
  # do stuff with url
```

But let's open the file outside of the loop, instead of reopening it each iteration.  This is why you only saw 10 results: talks 11-20 instead of the first ten as you thought.  (It would've been 21-30, except you looped on `page_count < total_pages`, which only processed the first two pages.)

And gather all the links at once, then write the output afterwards.  I've stripped out the HTML styling, which also makes the code easier to follow; instead, use CSS, possibly an inline <style> element, or add it back if you like.

```
import urllib2
from cgi import escape  # Important!
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def is_talk_anchor(tag):
  return tag.name == "a" and tag.findParent("dt", "thumbnail")
links = []
for pagenum in xrange(1, 4):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ted.com/talks?page=%d" % pagenum))
  links.extend(soup.findAll(is_talk_anchor))

out = open("test.html", "w")

print >>out, """<html><head><title>TED Talks Index</title></head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><th>#</th><th>Name</th><th>URL</th></tr>"""

for x, a in enumerate(links):
  print >>out, "<tr><td>%d</td><td>%s</td><td>http://www.ted.com%s</td></tr>" % (x + 1, escape(a["title"]), escape(a["href"]))

print >>out, "</table>"

# Or, as an ordered list:
print >>out, "<ol>"
for a in links:
  print >>out, """<li><a href="http://www.ted.com%s">%s</a></li>""" % (escape(a["href"], True), escape(a["title"]))
print >>out, "</ol>"

print >>out, "</body></html>"
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the "from cgi import escape"?

Comment: @AdamC.: If one of the URLs or titles includes a character that's special to HTML, namely &, <, or " (since I used double-quotes in one output), then escape() will handle them so you don't produce invalid markup.  You won't want anything else from the cgi module, but it happens to both be in the stdlib and contain this handy function. http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape